# catchall for BeginInvoke method so it doesn't close my application?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a catchall handler I can register for the BeginInvoke method in C#?

On startup in my MainForm, I have this code

```
        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(UIExceptionHandler);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
```

I thought that was enough but an exception in another form is taking down my application.  How do I deal with this?  (I really don't want to go into every user control I have an add a proxy BeginInvoke method with my own try..catch nor do I want to add it to every BeginInvoke call I have....that would be quite tedious compared to adding a catchall handler).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

[Here is the MSDN on SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx)

[Also, here is a SO question that might make more sense if you are seeing this in debug (JoshL's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545760/which-config-element-affects-exception-handling-with-unhandledexceptionmode-set). Basically, it defaults to automatic, and if the `jitDebugging` config is set to true (which it is if you are debugging), then the application will throw instead of catch into your handler.